# How to run Symfony2 application on Vagrant without nfs (on Windows, for example)?

Tags: windows, symfony, vagrant, nfs

Symfony2 application is very slow when you run it with default settings on Vagrant/Windows.

What one can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I have found so far is to move `vendor/` outside shared folder.

It doesn't require nfs and can be done easily with two simple changes.

One change in `composer.json`:

```
//filename: composer.json
{
    ...
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "vendor-dir": "/home/vagrant/symfony2app/vendor"
    },
    ...
}
```

and one change in `app/autoload.php`:

```
//filename: app/autoload.php
/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require '/home/vagrant/symfony2app/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The results are truly amazing. Esspecially on Windows.

More details here: http://by-examples.net/2014/12/09/symfony2-on-vagrant.html

Comment: That's a smart idea, my `vendor` contains about 12,000 files, using NFS to share these files would be incredibly slow.